# Fitting a large number of bars into a matplotlib barh graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I'm trying to make a horizontal bar graph with a large number of elements/bars with matplotlib's barh function. However, I'm having a couple of problems with bars being too close together and their labels being illegible (see image below):

- I first tried changing the figure size, setting figsize=(10,40) and increasing the height up from 40, to no avail.
- I also tried bumping up the spacing between bars from 0.2 to 0.3 (in the positions list), but it seems that going any higher than a spacing of 0.2 makes some of the bars disappear. In other words, there seem to be clusters of ~5 bars that are too close together that get spaced properly at 0.3, but all the bars between these clusters disappear.

The code is shown below (adapted from the mpl docs/examples). I'm sure there's rather an easy fix here that I'm just too much of a novice to realize. Alternatively, I could try graphing this in matlab but I prefer python for quality and simplicity. Are there improvements I could make that would make my bar graph legible?

Code:

```
genus = {'Parasutterella': 1, 'Anaerobaculum': 1, 'Clostridiales': 1, 'Butyrivibrio': 1, 'Anaerococcus': 1, 'Neisseria': 1, 'Campylobacter': 1, 'Intestinibacter': 1, 'Erysipelatoclostridium': 1, 'Tannerella': 1, 'Barnesiella': 1, 'Enterobacter': 1, 'Odoribacter': 1, 'Arcobacter': 1, 'Dialister': 1, 'Alistipes': 1, 'Collinsella': 2, 'Synergistes': 2, 'Burkholderiales': 2, 'Gordonibacter': 2, 'Tyzzerella': 2, 'Providencia': 2, 'Weissella': 2, 'Enterobacteriaceae': 2, 'Flavonifractor': 2, 'Prevotella': 2, 'Klebsiella': 2, 'Citrobacter': 2, 'Actinomyces': 2, 'Proteus': 2, 'Catenibacterium': 2, 'Propionibacterium': 2, 'Mitsuokella': 2, 'butyrate-producing': 2, 'Parvimonas': 2, 'Phascolarctobacterium': 2, 'Desulfovibrio': 2, 'Cedecea': 2, 'Finegoldia': 2, 'Slackia': 3, '[Bacteroides]': 3, 'Hafnia': 3, 'Acidaminococcus': 3, 'Bifidobacterium': 3, 'Sutterella': 3, 'Anaerofustis': 3, 'Paraprevotella': 3, 'Oxalobacter': 3, 'Yokenella': 3, 'Leuconostoc': 3, 'Dermabacter': 3, 'Megamonas': 4, 'Staphylococcus': 4, 'Fusobacterium': 4, 'Anaerostipes': 4, 'Bilophila': 4, 'Butyricicoccus': 4, 'Parabacteroides': 4, 'Erysipelotrichaceae': 4, 'Anaerotruncus': 4, 'Listeria': 4, 'Corynebacterium': 5, 'Pseudoflavonifractor': 5, 'Dorea': 5, 'Streptococcus': 6, 'Roseburia': 6, 'Helicobacter': 6, 'Eggerthella': 6, 'Acinetobacter': 6, '[Clostridium': 6, 'Ruminococcaceae': 6, 'Dysgonomonas': 6, '[Eubacterium]': 6, 'Enterococcus': 6, 'Subdoligranulum': 7, 'Faecalibacterium': 7, 'Blautia': 8, 'Holdemania': 8, 'Bacteroides': 8, 'Marvinbryantia': 8, 'Coprococcus': 9, 'Eubacterium': 9, 'Lactobacillus': 9, 'Paenisporosarcina': 9, 'Turicibacter': 9, 'Ruminococcus': 10, 'Coprobacillus': 11, 'Ralstonia': 11, 'Peptoclostridium': 11, 'Pseudomonas': 13, 'Desulfitobacterium': 14, 'Bacillus': 15, 'Streptomyces': 26, '[Clostridium]': 29, 'Paenibacillus': 32, 'Lachnospiraceae': 32, 'Clostridium': 35}
```

```
barWidth = 0.125

labels = list(genus.keys())
cols = len(labels)
bars = []
positions = [(i+1)*0.2 for i in range(cols)]
for key in labels:
    bars.append(genus[key])
    
    
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

rects = []
for i in range(len(bars)):
    if labels[i] in pos_genus:
        rects.append(ax.barh(y=positions[i], width=bars[i], height=barWidth, color='#000000',label='Gram Positive'))
    else:
        rects.append(ax.barh(y=positions[i], width=bars[i], height=barWidth, color='#E8384F',label='Gram Negative'))
    
ax.set_title('Genus')
    
ax.set_yticks(positions)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
ax.set_ylabel('Genus')
ax.set_xlabel('Number of Organisms')
#ax.set_ylim(positions[0]-barWidth,positions[-1]+barWidth)
ax.set_xlim(0,40)


blk_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='#000000', label='Gram Positive')
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='#E8384F', label='Gram Negative')
plt.legend(handles=[blk_patch, red_patch])
    
#plt.figure(figsize=(10,50))
bar_path = os.path.join(paths['Figures'], "{0}_horiz_bar.png".format(str('genus')))
plt.savefig(bar_path,dpi=300,bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Illegible barh plot:
[image]

Comment: What is `pos_genus`?

Comment: Did you try setting a smaller font? `ax.set_yticklabels(labels, fontsize=6)`? Also `ax.margins(y=0)` might help to reduce the whitespace. Further, you need to set the figsize in `fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=...)`. The call to `plt.figure()` creates a new figure, which isn't connected to the variable `ax`; please remove this call.

Comment: @JohanC That seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottBoston It's a list of strings for gram positive genera, to help label/color the bars. It's defined in another cell, but thanks for pointing that out.